# Probability that $x>y$ and $x>z$

Tags: probability, correlation, conditional-probability

I have three independent normally distributed variables:
$$x\sim N(0,1) $$
$$y\sim N(0,1) $$
$$z\sim N(0,1) $$

What it the probability that $x$ is greater than both $y$ and $z$ ?
$$P(x>y , x>z)$$

Analytically, I approached the problem this way:
$$P(x>y , x>z)=P(x>y) P(x>z) = 0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.25$$

But when I run simulations I get:
$$P(x>y , x>z)=0.33$$

What is wrong?

Comment: One way to approach the problem is to consider how many possible orders of the three there are, and then identify how many  of those are consistent with the condition..

Answer (score 5):

Because the events $x>y$ and $x>z$ are **not** independent, thus you can't write
$$P(x>y , x>z)=P(x>y) P(x>z)$$

It's $1/3$ because these continuous iid RVs have equal probability of being the maximum, and $x$ is just one of them.

Comment: thank you @gunes - Intuitively I suspected that (x > y) and (x > z) were correlated, but how to show that analytically?

Comment: Think simpler, and let $y=1, z=2$. What would $x>2$ tell you about $x>1$?

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at this is to note that the vector $(x,y,z)$ is [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), and since they are continuous random variables, the probability of a tie is zero.  Consequently, each possible order for the values is equally likely.  Here are all the possible orders and their probabilities, with a star next to the orders that satisfy your statement.

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Order} & & & \text{Probability} \\[6pt]
x<y<z & & & \tfrac{1}{6} & \\
x<z<y & & & \tfrac{1}{6} & \\
y<x<z & & & \tfrac{1}{6} & \\
y<z<x & & & \tfrac{1}{6} & * \\
z<x<y & & & \tfrac{1}{6} & \\
z<y<x & & & \tfrac{1}{6} & * \\
\end{matrix}$$

(Note that orderings with ties have zero probability when the random variables have a continuous distribution.)  Consequently, *regardless of the particular (continuous) distribution for the variables*, you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(x > y, x > z) = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}.$$